# XSLT access to line and column position in source file of target element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I’m looking for an XPath expression in XSLT that will give me the line and column number of the position in the input XML file where the matched element is. Perhaps looking like this:

```xml
<xsl:template match="//foo">
  element foo is at line <xsl:value-of select="...?" /> column <xsl:value-of select="...?" /> of the input file
</xsl:template>
```

Is there any way to do this with XSLT?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "column" and "line". Could you show us an example of the input and the corresponding output?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/ appears short on "line" or "column" references, so this would probably need to be an add-on function provided by whatever XML library is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a feature does not exist in XSLT simply because XSLT and XPath use an XDM instance to represent the XML document, which loses this information, and entity names, or DTD info.

This makes sense because from the point of view of XPath XML is not a file but a tree structure of a root, elements, attributes, children etc.

Here's are some suggestions to "fix" this, for instance if you want to report about errors in the XML file

- It is trivial to get an absolute XPath to any context node as a string, copy/paste this in any XPath tester and it will point directly to the node you want to report on, regardless of whether you removed whitespace or left lines intact.
- You can augment a file using the following process:

  - Process the file with something like XmlReader in C#, which knows the line, and simply place the line number in an attribute on each element, say `info:line`, `info:column`
  - Now, when you process this augmented XML file you can get this information using `@info:line` etc.
- In XSLT 3.0, with `xsl:try` and `xsl:catch`, the processor may issue information about the context node position, check your processor for information.
- if you don't mind using a processor-specific extension, you can use [`saxon:line-number`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/line-number.html) and [`saxon:column-number`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/column-number.html) with Saxon, but it obviously depends on how you load the document whether or not such info is available. Also, these functions only work in the commercial versions of Saxon, not the open-source ‘Home Edition’.

Since attributes do not have an order, nor do namespaces, you shouldn't try to attempt to get the physical positions of those.

Comment: Thanks, `saxon:line-number` is actually what I wanted! I don’t mind that it’s Saxon-specific since this is only for debug purposes.